# Java 7 on PowerPc

Tags: macos, java, unix, leopard, powerpc

I have several powermac G4 computers running leopard, and would like to use them as a test environment for my Java 7 based applications. I have looked online a bit but could not find any way to install java 7 on a powerpc computer. I wouldn't mind using linux or other alternative operating systems if necessary to get java 7, but would prefer to stay on os x if possible,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully built and run Java 7 on my Mac OS X 10.5.8 PPC, exactly OpenJDK version *1.7.0-internal-landonf_2009_12_16_12_54-b00*, using [these instructions](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/2009/12/16).

Comment: Thanks for sharing an OS X method. I'd be nice if someone would create an installer for Leopard.

Comment: I have bundled my [JDK7 build](http://dfiles.eu/files/xgo71ltfy). I hope it will run on your Mac OS X PPC.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPC is still an official architecture for Debian. The package [openjdk-7-jre](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-7-jre) is availible for powerpc and should run your Java 7 code.

Comment: This is about Leopard, not Debian.

Comment: @niutech - the question says "I wouldn't mind using linux"

Comment: @Mark - then "but would prefer to stay on os x if possible". It is possible, I have added the answer.

Comment: Debian has dropped official support for PowerPC based Macs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Java 7 is only available on OS X for Intel-based Macs running Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later.

The [Mac OS X System Requirements page for Java 7](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_sysreq-sm.jsp) states:

> Mac OS X System Requirements
>
> Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later.*
>   Administrator privileges for installation
>   64-bit browser
>   Note that installing Java on a Mac is performed on a system wide basis, for all users, and administrator privileges are required. You cannot install Java on a single-user basis.
>
> A 64-bit browser (Safari or Firefox, for example) is required to run Java 7 on Mac OS X. 32-bit browsers such as Chrome do not support Java 7 on the Mac platform.
>
> ****Users with Mac OS X versions 10.6 and below should go to Software Update under the Apple menu to look for updates.***

There are some very old releases available for PowerPC at [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/), but these may not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Powermac G4 is 32bit PowerPC/PPC based. PPC32 is only being maintained for Linux nowaday, but the good news is that the 32bit Java 8 from Azul Systems works on PowerMac G4 with Linux. We got OpenHab to work on this configuration.
This is not yet a free download but ask nicely enough and often enough and they make make it available.